# Why is there syntax error on "," in my python code?

Tags: python

```
money, c50000, c10000, c5000, c1000, c500, c100, c50, c10 = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

money = int(input("how much do you wanna change into ?"))

c50000 = money // 50000
money %= 50000
c10000 = money // 10000
money %= 10000
c5000 = money // 5000
money %= 5000
c1000 = money // 1000
money %= 1000
c500 = money // 500
money %= 500
c100 = money // 100
money %= 100
c50 = money // 50
money %= 50
c10 = money // 10
money %= 10

print("50000 : %d, 10000 : %d, 5000 : %d, 1000 : %d", % (c50000, c10000, c5000, c1000))
print("500 : %d, 100 : %d, 50 : %d, 10 : %d", % (c500,c100,c50,c10))
print("remain==> %d$" %money)
```

I'm using Python and it's program to divide money by 50000, 10000, 5000, 1000, 500, 50, 10.
I wonder why there is invalid syntax on `,` after `c10000`.

Comment: Post the exact error message and specify which line / occurance of c10000 it is after as it could be any.

Comment: Please repeat your tutorial on the "%" formatting in `print`.  The comma is incorrect.  Also, I strongly recommend that you update to f-strings, or even `format()`.

Comment: ...that is to say: `"string", % (...values...)` should instead be `"string" % (...values...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%` symbol should be between string and values you want to put in there, but **you have a comma separating them**.

Use it like this:

```
print("50000 : %d, 10000 : %d, 5000 : %d, 1000 : %d" % (c50000, c10000, c5000, c1000))
```

Also, as other are pointing out, you should think about migrating to [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).

Answer (score 0):

You had unnecessary comma before %, this code will work:

```
money, c50000, c10000, c5000, c1000, c500, c100, c50, c10 = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

money = int(input("how much do you wanna change into ?"))

c50000 = money // 50000
money %= 50000
c10000 = money // 10000
money %= 10000
c5000 = money // 5000
money %= 5000
c1000 = money // 1000
money %= 1000
c500 = money // 500
money %= 500
c100 = money // 100
money %= 100
c50 = money // 50
money %= 50
c10 = money // 10
money %= 10

print("50000 : %d, 10000 : %d, 5000 : %d, 1000 : %d" % (c50000, c10000, c5000, c1000))
print("500 : %d, 100 : %d, 50 : %d, 10 : %d" % (c500, c100, c50, c10))
print("remain==> %d$" % money)
```